# Change position of input filed for jQuery Mobile Filter List

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im using the jQuery Mobile Filter List:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-search-with-dividers.html

Is it possible to move the position of the input field so I can put it into a div already on my page?

Using jQuery's appendTo seems to work fine but its kind of a hacky solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what I found while searching for solution to a similar problem.

HTML code example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-id">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <input type="search" name="password" id="search" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="filter-div" data-filter="one">1</div>
        <div class="filter-div" data-filter="two">2</div>
        <div class="filter-div" data-filter="three">3</div>
        <div class="filter-div" data-filter="four">4</div>
        <div class="filter-div" data-filter="five">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code example:

```
$(document).delegate('#page-id', 'pageinit', function () {
    var $filterDivs = $('.filter-div');
    $('#search').bind('keyup change', function () {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $filterDivs.slideDown(500);
        } else {
            var regxp = new RegExp(this.value),
                $show = $filterDivs.filter(function () {
                    return ($(this).attr('data-filter').search(regxp) > -1);
                });
            $filterDivs.not($show).slideUp(500);
            $show.slideDown(500);
        }
    });
});
```

This way you can place your input text box anywhere on your page and it should properly filter a list of items you want.

JSFiddle DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/cZW5r/30/